# How do i make navigation bar tabs highlighted when selected? (no JS)

Tags: html, css, tabs, navbar

I'd like to have the navigation bar tabs highlighted in Yellow when they are clicked and staying like that until i click another tab. I need to use CSS :target selector and can't use JS.

I tried many combinations but the color of tabs is always white :(

```css
.Nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.Nav h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

.Nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0 none;
}

#Section-1,
#Section-2,
#Section-3,
#Section-4,
#Section-5 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.Nav h5:target a {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav">
  <h5><a href="#Section-1">Section 1</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-2">Section 2</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-3">Section 3</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-4">Section 4</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-5">Section 5</a></h5>
</div>

<div id="Section-1"> 11111111111 </div>
<div id="Section-2"> 222222222222 </div>
<div id="Section-3"> 33333333333 </div>
<div id="Section-4"> 4444444444444 </div>
<div id="Section-5"> 5555555555555555 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`:target` CSS pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) is used to select the element that's being selected by the ID selector (eg. `#Section-3`) instead of the element that has the anchor `href` property pointed to that ID.

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to select on the element that your URL is on with pure CSS with just the URL anchor. There's however a [`:local-link` CSS pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:local-link) that could be implemented in the future that solves this.

Modified the code to illustrate the behaviour of `:target`:

```css
.Nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.Nav h5 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
  color: white;
}

.Nav a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: inherit;
  outline: 0 none;
}

#Section-1,
#Section-2,
#Section-3,
#Section-4,
#Section-5 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 70px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

:target {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="Nav">
  <h5><a href="#Section-1">Section 1</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-2">Section 2</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-3">Section 3</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-4">Section 4</a></h5>
  <h5><a href="#Section-5">Section 5</a></h5>
</div>

<div id="Section-1">11111111111</div>
<div id="Section-2">222222222222</div>
<div id="Section-3">33333333333</div>
<div id="Section-4">4444444444444</div>
<div id="Section-5">5555555555555555</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but what i meant is that the navigation tabs become Yellow when they're clicked, not the text in the red squares... do you know what i mean?

Comment: Hi @JohnBoo, yes I understand, but unfortunately this is not yet supported in browser with just pure CSS

Comment: I've found this though: https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-tabs-using-target-selector/ it does exactly what i need in pure CSS but I can't make it work :/

Comment: Hi @JohnBoo, the solution works because the anchor link is the children of the element that has the `id` field to be selected. If they are not subsequent-sibling / children then there's no easy way to match them

Comment: Then how could I modify my HTML to make ti work that way? ‍♂️